# Finding ü (u with umlaut) using regular expressions

Tags: regex, python-2.7, unicode, utf-8, diacritics

I am using the following text snippet that contains the [letter ü](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fc/index.htm):

```
test für fur test
```

Here's the code:

```
import re

for m in re.finditer(r, line, re.IGNORECASE | re.UNICODE):
    print 'match:  ', m.group(0)
    print 'offset: ', m.start()
```

And there are three regular expressions:

```
r = ur'\bf(\u0075)r\b'    # finds 'fur', as expected
r = ur'\bf(\xc3\xbc)r\b'  # finds 'für', as expected
r = ur'\bf(\u00FC)r\b'    # does not find 'für'
```

The expression #1 and the #3 are similar; the only difference is the Unicode point (`u` vs `ü`). Why doesn't #3 work?

I can use #2 but it is less readable.

Comment: I have just matched `für` with your Regex 3. No idea why it does not work on your side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my test results.

```
>>> print re.findall(ur'\bf(\u0075)r\b', "test für fur test", re.I|re.U)
['u']
>>> print re.findall(ur'\bf(\xc3\xbc)r\b', "test für fur test", re.I|re.U)
['\xc3\xbc']
>>> print re.findall(ur'\bf(\u00FC)r\b', "test für fur test", re.I|re.U)
[]
```

These match your results exactly. I noticed the match for the second case was `['\xc3\xbc']`, then it hit me. `"test für fur test"` is a non-unicode string.

Here was my second set of tests with unicode strings.

```
>>> print re.findall(ur'\bf(\u0075)r\b', u"test für fur test", re.I|re.U)
[u'u']
>>> print re.findall(ur'\bf(\xc3\xbc)r\b', u"test für fur test", re.I|re.U)
[]
>>> print re.findall(ur'\bf(\u00FC)r\b', u"test für fur test", re.I|re.U)
[u'\xfc']
```

The regex is matching the binary representation in the string. So unicode strings match unicode characters, non-unicode strings match the UTF-8 encoded characters.

---

If you don't have a choice as to the type of sting you work with, you can always use `unicode()`.

```
>>> print re.findall(ur'\bf(\u00FC)r\b', unicode("test für fur test", "utf-8"), re.I|re.U)
[u'\xfc']
```

In your case

```
for m in regex.finditer(r, unicode(line, "utf-8"), regex.IGNORECASE | regex.UNICODE):
    print 'match:  ', m.group(0)
    print 'offset: ', m.start()
```

---

**NOTE**

Depending on the file encoding of your .py file, `ur'\bf(ü)r\b'` should also work.

```
>>> print re.findall(ur'\bf(ü)r\b', u"test für fur test", re.I|re.U)
[u'\xfc']
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are confusing yourself here.  The strings you are grepping are apparently not Unicode strings.

If they were, you would get `\u00fc` as expected.

```
>>> import re
>>> m = re.search(ur'f(\xc3\xbc|\u0075|\u00fc)r', u'für')
>>> m.group(1)
u'\xfc'
```

You would still have to cater for Unicode equivalence. The fully decomposed equivalent of [U+00FC](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00fc/index.htm) is a regular `u` followed by [COMBINING DIAERESIS (U+0308)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0308/index.htm).  Probably you will want to run `unicodedata.normalize('NFC', thing)` and make sure your regex always looks for the composed equivalent (or conversely go for `'NFD'` and fully decomposed); or perhaps switch to the [`regex` module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) which allegedly handles this better.

If you are dealing with UTF-8 and you know you are, the usual recommendation is to decode it to a Unicode string as soon as you read it into Python.  See e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html

Comment: You're absolutely right. I have a `UnicodeReader` class for that I didn't use this time, because I only wanted to test regex with German diacritic characters.

Comment: I tried to match `u'f\u00fcr'` against `u'fu\u0308r'` with `regex` and it didn't match, either.  Maybe I'm overlooking something, though.